# Combine two expressions using LINQ?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    var EXPEarners =
        from victor in ins.BattleParticipants
        where victor.GetComponent<TotalEXP>() != null
        select victor;
    foreach (GameObject victor in EXPEarners)
    {
        victor.GetComponent<TotalEXP>().value += EXPGain;
    }
```

I'm new to LINQ and I would like some help. Is there a way to combine these two blocks of code so I don't have to call `GetComponent()` twice? (I'm using Unity.) Perhaps introduce a temporary variable and use a foreach loop instead? But the whole purpose of using LINQ was to avoid the foreach.

Also, is there a way to inject methods in between the LINQ statements, like call a void method before I select the final result, in case I want to do something "in between?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this, but one small alteration to your query would get you to a single call:

First, get rid of the `null` check and simply return a map of `victor` and `component`:

```
var EXPEarners =
    from victor in ins.BattleParticipants
    select new {
        victor,
        component = victor.GetComponent<TotalEXP>()
    };
```

Then, loop over each pair, adding the experience points if the `component` isn't `null`:

```
foreach (var participant in EXPEarners)
{
    // can do something with participant.victor here
    if (participant.component != null)
        participant.component.value += EXPGain;
}
```

You could of course shorten this code up quite a bit, but if you do need to do something in between, you have the opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this alternative:

```
// Dosomething for every item in the list
ins.BattleParticipants.All(gameObject => Reward(gameObject, EXPGain));
```

Then you write a method to perform "Reward", which can be as complex as you like

```
    static bool Reward(GameObject gameObject, int EXPGain)
    {
        TotalEXP exp = gameObject.GetComponent<TotalEXP>();
        if (exp != null)
        {
            exp.value += EXPGain;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And if you want, you can chain these, so for example you can also call a "Bonus" for all those you rewarded (where Reward returned true)

```
// Reward all EXPGain in the list then give them a Bonus
ins.BattleParticipants.Where(gameObject => Reward(gameObject, EXPGain)).All(gameObject => Bonus(gameObject, BONGain));
```

Then you write a method to perform "Bonus"

```
    static bool Bonus(GameObject gameObject, int BONGain)
    {
        SomeOther soc = gameObject.GetComponent<SomeOther>();
        if (soc != null)
        {
            soc.value += BONGain;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to increment `TotalEXP` value and you don't use a retrived `GameObject` somewhere else you can use `let` and retrive the collection of `TotalEXP`:

```
    var TotalEXPs =
        from victor in ins.BattleParticipants
        let component = victor.GetComponent<TotalEXP>()
        where component != null
        select component;

    foreach (TotalEXP expin TotalEXPs)
    {
        exp.value += EXPGain;
    }
```

Otherwise, you can see @Cᴏʀʏ answer where you can retrive `GameObject` and it `TotalEXP`

Answer (score -1):

Try searching for the "let" statement on LINQ. Maybe it can help you.